# What keeps the immaterial soul inside the physical body?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, soul

By what methods the immaterial soul is contained within the material body during our lifetime?

Comment: See Rema here https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.6.1?lang=bi